# ASMX Webservice- Enabling HTTP POST [405 Method Not Allowed]

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, post, asmx

I have added the following line to the web.config file.But i keep getting

**HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE**

```
 <webServices>
          <protocols>
               <add name="HttpPost"/>
          </protocols>
     </webServices>
```

This is an ASMX Webservice.I need to make HTTP POST Calls to it to send some data.